# One function handles multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, switch-statement

Having some trouble getting this code to work. Simply want to handle each button case differently using one function instead of 3 separate ones. Some very old stackoverflow answers recommended using a switch, but I can't seem to get it working. I get no errors with the below code, but pushing the buttons doesn't print anything to console.

```
  myFunction = button => {
      var x = button.id;
      switch (x) {
          case 'All Saves':
              console.log('All Saves');
              break;
          case 'Threads':
              console.log('Threads');
              break;
          case 'Comments':
              console.log('Comments');
              break;
          default:
              return false;
      }
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="btn-group">
          <button type="button" onClick={this.myFunction.bind(this)} id="All Saves">All Saves</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.myFunction.bind(this)} id="Threads">Threads</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.myFunction.bind(this)} id="Comments">Comments</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      ) 
  }
```

Comment: You have `myFunction` defined as a variable, whereas you are defining the click handler to be `this.myFunction`. There are not always going to be the same thing.

Comment: Is your function called?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(x);`? Or `console.log(button)`?

Comment: @VLAZ Not sure I understood you.

Comment: @SimonThiel I'm expecting it to be called on click. I don't call it outside of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to access the event's `target` property:

```
  myFunction = button => {
      var x = button.target.id;
      switch (x) {
          case 'All Saves':
              console.log('All Saves');
              break;
          case 'Threads':
              console.log('Threads');
              break;
          case 'Comments':
              console.log('Comments');
              break;
          default:
              return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Renaming `button` to `event` would make sense too.

Comment: It's the convention.

Comment: Or using `this` instead of `button`.

Comment: @VLAZ — That won't work. Look at what `bind` does. Note that `bind` is being used.

Comment: @Quentin ah, damn. Forgot about that. You're right - the `bind` will prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

call the function with the click event :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  myFunction = event => {
    var x = event.target.id;
    switch (x) {
        case 'All Saves':
            console.log('All Saves');
            break;
        case 'Threads':
            console.log('Threads');
            break;
        case 'Comments':
            console.log('Comments');
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="btn-group">
          <button type="button" onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)} id="All Saves">All Saves</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)} id="Threads">Threads</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)} id="Comments">Comments</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class MyButtons extends React.Component {
  myFunction = event => {
    var x = event.target.id;
    switch (x) {
        case 'All Saves':
            console.log('All Saves');
            break;
        case 'Threads':
            console.log('Threads');
            break;
        case 'Comments':
            console.log('Comments');
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="btn-group">
          <button type="button" onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)} id="All Saves">All Saves</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)} id="Threads">Threads</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={e => this.myFunction(e)} id="Comments">Comments</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyButtons />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is the working example for your problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-night-di8de?fontsize=14